# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element does not exist in cache

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm receiving `StaleElementReferenceException` when I'm trying to click an element with in a loop. Following is the code:

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.navigate().to("URL");
WebElement Links=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='chromemenu']"));
List <WebElement> AllLinks=Links.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(AllLinks.size());
//String start_xpath="//*[@id='chromemenu']/ul/li[";     
//String end_xpath="]/a";

for(int i=1;i<AllLinks.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(AllLinks.get(i).getText());
    System.out.println(AllLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    //AllLinks.get(i).click();
        //This is where i am clicking  approach 1
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath(start_xpath+i+end_xpath)).click(); 
        //This is where i am clicking  approach 2
    //driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Comment: I added WebElement Links1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='chromemenu']"));
  List <WebElement> AllLinks1=Links1.findElements(By.tagName("a")); with in my loop and it started working.

Comment: I don't think adding the declaration of Links1 and AllLinks1 within your loop had anything to do with it. Was it perhaps a timing issue instead? I suspect you were clicking on 1 link then rapidly on the next one possibly while the page was still loading. I'd suggest looking into WebDriverWait

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to click a link while looping the list.
You should save the link in another element and click it after the loop is completed to avoid this error